# The configuration information describing this enterprise is not available - Error I receive

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 installed and when I navigate to 'AD DS'  and try to go to 'Active Directory Domains and Trust' the error I receive is

"The configuration information describing this enterprise is not available. The server is not operational. "

Any ideas as to what causes this error?

Comment: You have at least one Windows Server 2012 R2 installed, do you have more than one Windows Server? Is the server you are working with a domain controller itself? If not, is it joined to a domain?

Answer (score 1):

Are you blocking port 389? Active directory runs on LDAP.  LDAP uses port 389, by default, to communicate with Directory Service servers.  One reason you're getting that message is due to 389 being blocked (a firewall rule or WFP).  If that is true, then you shouldn't be able to use any of the AD tools.

EDIT:  thought of another reason you're getting the message.  It could be all or some of your domain's SRV records missing, damaged, whatever.  To reregister the SRV records, restart the Netlogon service on your domain controller.